# Python DictWriter appending status in a column in input file using loop and if else condition

Tags: python

I am trying to automate a work using Code 1 and it works fine. But I need to update the status of each row in a column of the input file whether it has been voided or not voided. I am building Code 2, but i am not successful (code is incomplete). I also have following questions:

1. Can't I use `DictWriter` without `DictReader` in selenium for both reading file and writing one column?
2. I used segui as variable to check if the button is available in the webpage and i tried to store the text of button value in the variable, is this the correct method?
3. Is `writer.writerow()` method is correct to append STATUS column?

Input File Data:

CONTEXT_ID,TRXN_ID,STATUS
12843,8151568, 
13122,8160706,

Code 1: (successfully running)

```
import csv
path = r"C:\Users\maxx\Downloads\CSV\file9.csv"
file = open(path, newline = '')
obj = csv.DictReader(file)
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://prodmirror.url.com')
URL_PATTERN = 'https://prodmirror.url.com/{}/42/space/transactionvoid.esp?TRANSACTIONID={}'
for row in obj:
    url = URL_PATTERN.format(row['CONTEXT_ID'], row['TRXN_ID'])
    driver.get(url)
    find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Void This Transaction']").click()
```

Code 2: (incomplete code)

```
import csv
path = r"C:\Users\maxx\Downloads\CSV\file9.csv"
file = open(path, newline = '')
fieldnames = ['CONTEXT_ID','TRXN_ID','STATUS']
obj = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://prodmirror.url.com')
URL_PATTERN = 'https://prodmirror.url.com/{}/42/space/transactionvoid.esp?TRANSACTIONID={}'
for row in obj:
    url = URL_PATTERN.format(row['CONTEXT_ID'], row['TRXN_ID'])
    driver.get(url)
    segui = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Void This Transaction']").text
    if segui == 'Void This Transaction':
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Void This Transaction']").click()
        writer.writerow({'STATUS': 'Voided'})
    else:
        writer.writerow({'STATUS': 'Not Voided'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You iterate over your reader while writing to your writer

```
import io, csv, random

data = '''\
CONTEXT_ID,TRXN_ID,STATUS
2843,8151568,
13122,8160706,
'''

choices = ['Voided', 'Not Voided']

f = io.StringIO(data)
o = io.StringIO()

reader = csv.DictReader(f)
writer = csv.DictWriter(o, reader.fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
for d in reader:
    # determine status here
    status = random.choice(choices)
    # set status
    d['STATUS'] = status
    writer.writerow(d)

print(o.getvalue())
```